# bar chart with different color bar for each items with legands

Tags: c#, jquery, google-visualization, column-chart

Need to create a column chart with items in the x axis and values in y axis, when displaying the columns in the chart I need to show each items( each columns) in different colors and show this details in the legend,
I have used below code

```
 var jData =GetData();

    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    tdata.addColumn('string', 'items');
    tdata.addColumn('number', 'values');

    for (var i = 0; i < jData.length; i++) {
        tdata.addRow([jData[i].Item, jData[i].Value]);
    }

    var options = {
        hAxis: {

        },
        vAxis: {

        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('div1'));
    chart.draw(tdata, options);
```

when rendering the graph it shows as below

[image: column chart]

if I add x axis and y axis text using below code , it will not show each items name in x axis,

```
var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Item'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'value'
        }
    };
```

also all the items names are not rendering in the x- axis,

How do I show each items in different colors and x- axis name and item names in x- axis ?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple ways to color bars

1) by default, each series in the data table will be a different color
if all of the y-axis values are in the same column,
they will be the same color
which means you need more than one column in the data table

however, having multiple columns will cause the series' to group on the x-axis
if there is only one value per series,
this will cause the column to be off-center from the label
to correct this issue, use option --> `isStacked: true`

see following working snippet...

note: in this example, the `colors` option is used to provide custom colors
remove this option to use the chart's default colors

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y3');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y4');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y5');
    data.addRows([
       ['Item 001', 200, null, null, null, null, null],
       ['Item 002', null, 220, null, null, null, null],
       ['Item 003', null, null, 240, null, null, null],
       ['Item 004', null, null, null, 260, null, null],
       ['Item 005', null, null, null, null, 280, null],
       ['Item 006', null, null, null, null, null, 300]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      chartArea: {
        bottom: 80
      },
      colors: ['#e53935', '#8e24aa', '#1e88e5', '#43a047', '#ffb300', '#f4511e'],
      hAxis: {
        slantedText: true,
        title: 'Item'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'value'
      },
      isStacked: true,
      height: 400
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

2) another way to color columns is using a [style column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole)

however, style column roles do not sync with the legend

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
    data.addRows([
       ['Item 001', 200, '#e53935'],
       ['Item 002', 220, '#8e24aa'],
       ['Item 003', 240, '#1e88e5'],
       ['Item 004', 260, '#43a047'],
       ['Item 005', 280, '#ffb300'],
       ['Item 006', 300, '#f4511e']
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      chartArea: {
        bottom: 80
      },
      hAxis: {
        slantedText: true,
        title: 'Item'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'value'
      },
      height: 400
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

*note:* if the x-axis labels are cutoff, use the following option to allow more room...

```
  chartArea: {
    bottom: 80
  },
```

see above snippets...

Comment: here x axis values (items ) are dynamic not fixed in size